Galatians 1:19 the brother of the Lord
Could any of you respond to Jesus mysticist like Richard carrier on Galatians 1:19. He claims James (Jesus' brother) is not in the category of apostles. Can you prove that James is in the category of apostles?

Gal 1:18, 19 - Only after three years did I go up to Jerusalem to
confer with Cephas, and I stayed with him fifteen days. But I saw none
of the other apostles except James, the Lord’s brother.


Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

Please link the reference you are quoting.  In any case, this verse is very good evidence.

It depends on how one defines "apostle".
Quoting GotQuestions:
The word apostle means “one who is sent out.” In the New Testament, there are two primary usages of the word apostle.

The first is in specifically referring to the twelve apostles of Jesus Christ.
The second is in generically referring to other individuals who are
sent out to be messengers/ambassadors of Jesus Christ.

If we take the first definition, then it's true that James was very likely not one of the 12 apostles and instead was the half-brother of Jesus.

Because James the disciple was an early martyr (Acts 12:2), the likely
candidate for the authorship of this epistle is James, the brother of
Jesus. [1]

If we take the broader second definition then James was certainly an apostle.
We read in Galatians 1:18-19 NKJV

18 Then after three years I went up to Jerusalem to see Peter, and
remained with him fifteen days. 19 But I saw none of the other
apostles except James, the Lord’s brother.

Here, James, the brother of Jesus, is referred to as an apostle. Here, Paul describes a visit to Jerusalem where he meets with Peter and James, the brother of Jesus. Paul refers to James as an apostle, indicating that he is one of the select few who had witnessed the risen Christ and whose teaching held authority.
According to Biblestudytools:

1 Corinthians 15:7 specifically names James as one to whom Jesus
appeared after His Resurrection. Seeing his dead brother walking and
talking, James believes that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God sent
to save people from their sins.
When he later writes the Epistle of James, he introduces himself not
as the brother of Jesus or a leader of the church but as simply,
“James, a servant of God and of the Lord Jesus Christ” (James 1:1).
Immediately after Jesus ascends to heaven, Acts 1:14 finds James with
the apostles, praying and waiting for the promised Holy Spirit. James
is one of the 120 filled with the Holy Spirit at Pentecost, the day
the Church begins (Acts 2:1-4). From the moment he encounters Jesus
the Risen Lord, James is whole-heartedly devoted to serving Him and
His Church.

This being said, the inclusion of a book in the biblical canon did not depend solely on the author being one of the twelve apostles. The early Christian church used several criteria to determine what books appeared in the canon. Including:

Apostolic Authority: They included books that were written by
apostles or an author in special relationship to an apostle, such as
Mark, Luke, and James.
Consistency: The teachings of the book had to be consistent with the
accepted doctrines and practices of the church.
Widespread Use: The book had to be widely used and accepted by the
Christian community.
Divine Qualities: The book had to bear evidence of inspiration, such as,
high moral and spiritual values that would reflect a work of the Holy
Spirit.




References




Books of the Bible - how they were chosen as canon. (2018, June 7). Bible Sprout. https://www.biblesprout.com/articles/bible/canon-books/



